# Querying two indices or join results from two queries in Elastic search using Nest.net

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, nest

I have following requirement.
Index#1: Personal Data
Index#2: Geography locations

Due to some concerns we have normalized data into two indices. Based on requirement I will have to get personal information and geographical info either in single Elastic query or query first index and query second index and join in the client.

I have been looking and multiple options came up.

1. Chain query
2. Add two indices in single search request.

I am fairly new and i dont have a way to test both the options. Any suggestions or pointers will be a great help. Also if you know where we can have similar example like a sandbox i will start looking there.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the concerns that lead to splitting data into two indices? It might be good to add these to the question, as this could be an XY problem

Comment: Its not in my control and different team manages it and is designed that way.